# kendo ui back button breaks my app navigation

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I have tried to get the data-role="backbutton" kendo mobile ui feature to work but I am having issues. When testing the app on my iPhone 4 I get stuck in my app because the back button breaks the UX.

What happens is that when I am testing, I click heaps of back buttons (as they are used quite heavily in my app) and then randomly one decides to slide the previous view into the screen but only goes halfway and then snaps back (or some other type of visual glitch occurs). Then after that, all my navigation breaks down and I get stuck in the last view that I was in. Or better yet the links go to places that they are not supposed to. My tab bar does not work and either do links in the header. I have to exit the app completely, remove it from operating and try again. Seriously something wrong going on here.

I have tried to programatically add the back button by following the Kendo UI documentation but that does not work either. I am left with a button that does absolutely nothing when clicked - it may not even solve the issue anyway. I have looked using developer console in Google Chrome but I can't see any obvious issues.

Has anyone using Kendo Mobile UI experienced this issue before?

Comment: I have used it in my app..its working good....have you implemented the bak functionality on your own?

Comment: At the moment I am just incorporating the data-role="backbutton" functionality into the <a> tag. I did try to do it with Javascript but had no luck. Bear in mind my application goes about 3 layers deep with the back nav. There is heaps of linked views (that i have in separate html files).

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the latest release of the Kendo UI build and the problem seems to have been resolved. Surprising! I assumed the Kendo framework was a bit more mature to be experiencing such a big issue. It was occurring when using slide transitions in navigation. Here is a link to the bug post on Github https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/66